# Complex grouping and averages in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model structure like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
   published = models.DateTimeField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
   authors = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I I wanted to count the `Books` by each author. This was easy because I could do: `Author.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('book'))`.

I'm having a lot of difficulty calculating these:

- number of unique categories per author.
- average number of books written in a category by an author
- (This is a tough one.) the average duration between the first and last book written by an author in a category.

I'm not an ORM query guru and if I had to tackle this issue, I'd probably end up using a lot loops and other iterations to calculate this but I know that it isn't the right way to do this.

(I know that some of the things in this scenario are weird e.g. a unique constraint on the author's name, but this was the best example I found to illustrate my issue.)

Any help on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch, hard ones.

Since these are not informations that you will need often to be refreshed, I would suggest you add 3 fields to the `Author` model, then attach a post_save signal on the `Book` model: every time a book is created, you just calculate those values and store them in the `Author` model.

You will then be able to filter them easily, it will be very fast to display, and the time to calculate it will be almost unoticeable when saving occurs anyway.